# Подстановка значений с помощью php

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте, есть текстовый файл с 20 значениями. Нужен файл обработчик php, который бы брал, например, 3, 10, 15, значения из этого текстового файла и подставлял куда требуется. Например, в html таблицу:

```
<table border="1px">
    <tr>
          <td>Значение 3</td>
          <td>Значение 10</td>
          <td>Значение 15</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Вопрос задан повторно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/439573/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-php

Answer (score 1):

Можно считывать используя эту функцию http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php

например вот так

```
$section = file_get_contents('test.txt', NULL, NULL, 1, 14);
var_dump($section);
```

указываете количество символов если необходимо или просто так

```
$section = file_get_contents('test.txt');
 var_dump($section);
 // получаем строку, затем формируем из нее массив и выводим

 $res = explode(',',$section);
 $strings = '<tr>';
 foreach($res as $str) {

     $strings .= '<td>'.$str.'</td>';
 }
$strings .= '</tr>';
echo $strings;
```